# Exporting a graph to csv

Tags: php, csv

I am generating bar graph using php JPgraph library for a report. I want to export the report to csv. For that I am writing the html to csv using PHP. But graph does not exporting to csv. It shows link image cannot be displayed. There is no physical image .

report.php

```
<script src="js/customer_report.js"></script>
 <div><a href="#" onclick="return htmlToExcel();" /></div>
<table><tr>
<td width="50%" colspan=5 >
    <h2>Avg. by Day of Week</h2>
    <img width="90%" height="500" align="center" src="../../dhr_reports_1.php" />
</div>

</tr></table>
```

dhr_reports_1.php

```
<?php
include('includes/includes.php');
require_once ('includes/classes/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('includes/classes/jpgraph/jpgraph_bar.php');

$id = $_SESSION['ad_account_adword_id'];

$endDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 days"));

$startDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-30 days")); 


$sql = "SELECT ad_Date , SUM(ad_Clicks) ad_Clicks, SUM(ad_Conversions) ad_Conversions,ad_DayOfWeek , 

 case when ad_DayOfWeek='Sunday' then 1 
 when ad_DayOfWeek='Monday' then 2 
 when ad_DayOfWeek='Tuesday' then 3 
 when ad_DayOfWeek='Wednesday' then 4 
 when ad_DayOfWeek='Thursday' then 5 
 when ad_DayOfWeek='Friday' then 6 
 else 7 end as day
 FROM adword_campaign_reports where ad_Date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' and ad_account_id='$id' group by ad_DayOfWeek order by day; ";

$results = $main -> getResults($sql);

foreach($results as $result){

    $date = $result->ad_DayOfWeek ;

    $dataArray[] = $result->ad_Clicks ;
    $dataArray1[] = $result->ad_Conversions ;
    $datax[] = $date ;
}


$datazero=array(0,0,0,0);

$graph = new Graph(500,400);
$graph->title->Set('Avg. by Day of Week');
$graph->img->SetMargin(40,40,30,50);
// Setup Y and Y2 scales with some "grace"  
$graph->SetScale("textlin");
$graph->SetY2Scale("lin");
$graph->yaxis->scale->SetGrace(30);
$graph->y2axis->scale->SetGrace(30);

//$graph->ygrid->Show(true,true);
$graph->ygrid->SetColor('#0000ff','lightgray@0.5');

// Setup graph colors
$graph->SetMarginColor('gray');
$graph->y2axis->SetColor('#0000ff');
$graph->yaxis->SetColor('green');


// Create the "dummy" 0 bplot
$bplotzero = new BarPlot($datazero);

// Create the "Y" axis group
$ybplot1 = new BarPlot($dataArray);
//$ybplot1->value->Show();
$ybplot1->value->SetColor('green');
$ybplot1->SetFillColor('green');
$ybplot1->SetWidth(0.6);
$ybplot1->SetLegend("Clicks","green");
$ybplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($ybplot1,$bplotzero));

// Create the "Y2" axis group
$ybplot2 = new BarPlot($dataArray1);
//$ybplot2->value->Show();
$ybplot2->value->SetColor('#0000ff');
$ybplot2->SetFillColor('#0000ff');
$ybplot2->SetWidth(0.6);
$ybplot2->SetLegend("Conversions","#0000ff");
$y2bplot = new GroupBarPlot(array($bplotzero,$ybplot2));

// Setup X-axis labels
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels($datax);
//$graph->xaxis->SetLabelAngle(50);


// Add the grouped bar plots to the graph
$graph->Add($ybplot);
$graph->AddY2($y2bplot);

// .. and finally stroke the image back to browser
$graph->Stroke();



?>
```

customer_report.js

```
function htmToExcel(){


    var html = $("#summery_report_id").html();

    $.post('servicefiles/html_excel.php',{html:html},function(data){

        if(data==1){

            $("#downloadHTML").css('display','none');
            $("#downloadLink").css('display','');

            window.open('phpHtmlExcel.php','_blank');

        }

        });

    return false ;
}
```

html_excel.php

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../includes/includes.php';
$html=$_REQUEST['html'];
$_SESSION['html']=$html ;
echo 1;
?>
```

phpHtmlExcel.php

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/includes.php';
$file=phpHtmltoExcel.xls";
$test=$_SESSION['html'];
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $test;
?>
```

The graph is not importing to Excel sheet . How can I import the graph to excel. ?

Comment: Read this:- http://jpgraph.net/doc/faq.php. Especially 2-6 part